# How to check different data have same col. names with loop

Tags: r

I have 12 month data of air pollution. I want to test wether the columns are same across 12 month without repetition.

My data is X2016_1, X2016_2 ... X2016_12.

```
colnames(X2016_1) == colnames(X2016_2)
colnames(X2016_2) == colnmaes(X2016_3)    
                  .
                  .
                  .
colnames(X2016_11)==colnames(X2016_12)
```

Can I test these with a loop so that I can avoid repetition?
I am open to change the data names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the dataframes in a list, get their column names find out the common ones between all of them using `Reduce` + `intersect` and compare it with column names of any of the dataframe.

```
all(Reduce(intersect, lapply(mget(ls(pattern = 'X2016')), colnames)) == colnames(X2016_1))
```